# Bandwidth and load transient

Tags: transient

In [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/FCY_Lee/publication/3280631_Critical_Bandwidth_for_the_Load_Transient_Response_of_Voltage_Regulator_Modules/links/589883d24585158bf6f6b902/Critical-Bandwidth-for-the-Load-Transient-Response-of-Voltage-Regulator-Modules.pdf)
"*Critical Bandwidth for the Load Transient Response of Voltage Regulator Modules*",
they have an equation about average inductor current during the step-down transient.

They don't show the derivation. How to arrive at this equation ?

> ... the  step response  inductor  current  with  voltage-mode  control ...
>
> With the loop closed,the oscillation frequency is modified to the level of the control bandwidth,  which  is  much  faster  than  the  condition  in  the open loop.  The inductor  current  rising time  is approximately *a quarter* of the oscillation period. Thus, the average inductor current during the step-down transient is about
> [image]

Comment: Insufficient information to answer. Please link to the original document.

Comment: Better yet, quote the relevant part here (with attribution) or paraphrase it. Links disappear frequently.

Comment: As others said, we need to review the actual document to understand your question. But the expression you shared seems to be for the instantaneous current (\$i_L(t)\$), not for the average current (which wouldn't be dependent on \$t\$).

Comment: @Andyaka https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1353336

Comment: @rdtschttps://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1353336

Comment: @ThePhoton https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1353336

Comment: Not got access.

Comment: @Andyaka Can I mail you?

Comment: I did think about what the formulas meant but I didn't have a clue. You should post a fuller extract; one that is more self-contained.

Comment: how to post figure in this comment

Comment: @AJN I give the link

Comment: @Jason It looks like a **linear approximation**. Figure 2 and 6 hint the same. They also say "*inductor current rising time is approximately a quarter of the oscillation period*". So, it is not a derived formula, but *probably* an approximation based on the response shape.

Comment: @AJN  OK  I got it. I thought it is derived formula, so I am confused. thanks

Comment: @AJN thank you for correcting my wrong sentence, the english is not my language.